# How can i show only the right/left halt of a background image on my page?

Tags: html, css

I use a table to show several images. I need to show the left half an image in the first td-element and the right half of it in the second td-element. This is because some of the images have double width as others. I thought i use a div and set this image as background image for the first two td-elements using a child-div. Now i am fiddling around to make it work using css.

**Any suggestions?**

Update:  Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BkAcu/2/

Comment: Is there some code somewhere we can see?

Comment: here is my working solution inspired by RobW: http://jsfiddle.net/BkAcu/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `background-position: <horizontal> <vertical>` where `<horizontal>` and `<vertical>` are background offsets, in conjunction with `background-repeat: no-repeat`.

Set the `background-position` to a negative value, to move the bg to the left.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position

Example (assume your TDs to have a width of 100px, and the image to be 200px);

```
#td1, #td2 {
    background: url("200.png") no-repeat;
}
#td2 {
    background-position: -100px;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to scale down the images too? case: image 200x200 px need to be scaled to 100x100 px

Comment: Only using CSS3, which is currently supported by the newest version of all major browsers, see **[`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size)**.